# Is it safe to restart laravel queue worker by update/restart/reload supervisord

Tags: php, laravel, queue, supervisord

In [Laravel's docs](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/queues#queue-workers-and-deployment), it is recommended to use `php artisan queue:restart` to restart the queue worker so that no job is interrupted while being processed:

> This command will instruct all queue workers to gracefully exit after they finish processing their current job so that no existing jobs are lost. Since the queue workers will exit when the `queue:restart` command is executed, you should be running a process manager such as Supervisor to automatically restart the queue workers.

However, sometimes I would like to `reload/restart` with `supervisorctl` to make all config take effect. I think `supervisorctl` will send `SIGTERM` etc. signals to the `php artisan` process. Will this restarting process interrupt running jobs?

Comment: I believe supervisorctl restart results in a graceful shutdown, i.e. a running job is completed first. What do you mean with "to make all config to take effect"? You shouldnt have to update your supervisor config all the time. If you're talking about the PHP code/config, that should work either way since as soon as you restart the queue worker, the state of the php files is also refreshed.

Comment: @Flame Not correct, when using supervisorctl restart, it completely kills all running jobs during process, which sucks, but as of testing today that's the results I found, and also queue:restart is unreliable using forge.

Comment: @tmarois as far as I know the stopsignal will be `SIGTERM` which is regarded as a graceful/polite shutdown signal (in contradiction to `SIGKILL`). It is however up to the process what it does with that signal.